# Rolling in V shaped groove

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

[image: Diagram]

In this set up I've been asked to work out the linear acceleration down the slope. It's said to be instantaneously rolling around the axis AB

1. $Ma=Mg\sin(\theta)-2F$ where $F$ is the frictional force from the contacts.
2. $I=2MR^2/5+MR^2\sin^2(\phi/2)= MR^2(2/5+\sin^2(\phi/2))$ via parallel axis theorem.

However as the frictional forces act through the axis AB they don't exert a torque about the axis of rotation and so I'm not sure how to make any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

Start with the height difference between *AB* and the center. I have $h=R \sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$. Now you calculate the torque applied to the ball center as $\tau_C = (2 F) h$

- Sum of forces along groove $$ M g \sin \theta - 2 F = M a $$
- Sum of forces perpendicual to groove $$2 N - M g \cos \theta = 0 $$
- Sum of torques about the center of mass ($I_C = \frac{2}{5} M R^2$) $$ h (2 F) = I_C \alpha = (\frac{2}{5} M R^2)(\frac{a}{h})$$

Solve the above three equations for $a$, $F$ and $N$. I have $$\begin{align} a &= \frac{M g h^2 \sin(\theta)}{I_C+M h^2} \\ 2 F & = \frac{I_C M g \sin(\theta)}{I_C+M h^2} \\ 2 N &= M g  \cos(\theta) \end{align} $$

Note the denominator is the mass moment of inertia about *AB*, same as what you found using the parallel axis theorem. You can also pull out an effective mass $m_{eff} = M + \frac{I_C}{h^2}$ such that $$M g \sin\theta = m_{eff} a$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit confused because your solution doesn't take into account that it is "instantaneously rolling around the axis AB". Also you've assumed that it doesn't slip, which is guess must tie in to the idea of it "instantaneously rolling around the axis AB"? It does however give and answer that arrives at the 'show that' result so it's definitely correct

Comment: I do implicitly account for no slip by $\alpha = \frac{a}{h}$. If the velocity at _AB_ is zero it sets the kinematic relation of $v-\omega h = 0$ which I differentiate to get $a - \alpha h = 0$

Comment: Notice that I am glossing over some sign convetions (positive rotation ,etc) but the end result is the same.

Comment: Check for slipping when $F \gt \mu N$. When slipping occurs $\alpha \ne \frac{a}{h}$ and you have both $a$ and $\alpha$ as unknowns, but $F$ is known. In the end you still have 3 equations and 3 unknowns.